# Test data on AI with softmax (1D Array to 2D Array)

Tags: python, arrays, testing, artificial-intelligence, jupyter

I am currently trying to test a model I trained in jupyter notebooks but I keep getting errors and I'm unsure how to structure the code in order for the model to predict an output. 
Here is the code for my training of the model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(400, input_dim=features,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(150, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(80, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.save_weights("testSave.hdf5")
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.33,epochs=15)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The code works and compiles fine. 
Here is the code for attempting to create a new record and test it on the model trained above.

```
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(400, input_dim=features, activation='tanh'))
model2.add(Dense(150, activation='tanh'))
model2.add(Dense(80, activation='tanh'))
model2.add(Dense(40, activation='tanh'))
model2.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model2.load_weights("testSave.hdf5")
newData = random.rand(features) # Creates a new array of 87 instances (amount of features I have)
reshaped_to_2d = np.reshape(newData, (-1, 2)) # Attempting to reshape to 2D array as this is what an error is telling me to do. This doesnt work
scaler = preprocessing.Normalizer().fit(reshaped_to_2d)
newDataN = scaler.transform(reshaped_to_2d)
result = model2.predict_classes((newDataN), axis=1)
for item in result:
    print("Predicted Value: ", item[0])
```

The model throws an error at this line `reshaped_to_2d = np.reshape(newData, (-1, 2))` saying that it cannot convert an array of 87 instances to an array of 2. This may be a really trivial problem but I'm struggling understanding it and cannot find help online. Any help is great, thank you.

Error returned is in the picture below. 
[image]

This is the code I use to create the model so it can train on 87 columns * 100000 rows.

```
seed = 34
random.seed(seed)
features = 87
classes = 5
n = 100000
errors = 0.4
# Truncate
redundant = int(features/4)
# Classification dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=n, n_classes=classes, n_features=features, \
random_state = 1,n_informative =20, flip_y=errors, \
n_redundant=redundant)
# reshape y to 2D array, it needs to be to append
y = reshape(y, (-1, 1))
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
rescaledX = scaler.fit_transform(X)
Xy = concatenate((rescaledX,y),axis=1)
savetxt("myCAData.csv", Xy, delimiter=",")
data = read_csv("myCAData.csv")
print(Xy[:5])
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
```

Comment: what is the shape of X and Y in your fit function? What is the error line that is returned by python? Can you edit your message please?

Comment: @YoannA. I have added what you commented on. The X is 87 in length and the  Y is 5(softmax)

Answer (score 1):

The new shape you have provided when you are using np.reshape() is not valid because the data you have generated is of length 87 which is an odd number and when you want to split it into two columns of the same length which is not possible because 87 / 2 is not an integer. When you use np.reshape with a parameter -1 in the length tuple, the length of the input vector must be divided by the second number.

You have said that the input feature vector is of length 87 so I don't get your point when you want to split in a 2D vector the newData to input to your model. Can you explain more the logic behind so I may help you to solve this problem of dimension?